# implementation of stacks using vector - segmentation fault in peek() function

Tags: c++, vector, stack, fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Stack{
  public:
  vector<string> vc;
  int length=0;

  void peek(){
     if(vc.size()==0){
         cout<< "The stack is empty"<<endl;
     }
     cout<< vc[length]<<endl; //----> does not work;
     //cout<<vc[vc.size()-1]; ---> does not work either
     //cout<<vc.end(); ----> does not work either;
  }

  void add(string value){
      vc.push_back(value);
      length++;
  }

  void pop(){
      vc.erase(vc.end());
      length--;
  }

  void show(){
    for (int i=0;i<vc.size();i++){
        cout << vc[i] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }


};

int main()
{
    Stack mystack;
    mystack.peek();
    mystack.add("Hello");
    mystack.peek();
    mystack.add("frands");
    mystack.add("chai");
    mystack.add("pee");
    mystack.add("lo");
    mystack.show();
    mystack.peek();
    mystack.pop();
    mystack.show();
}
```

problem 1->
the problem arises in the peek() function i cannot access the last element in my vector space i get returned with a segmentation fault(core dump) error.

problem 2->
and while pasting this code on stack overflow i had to manually add 4spaces in each code line how to do this at one step (sorry for a silly question).

Comment: `vc[length]` will always be out of bounds of the vector. Remember that vector indexes (just like array indexes) are *zero* based. So a vector with `length`number of elements will have indexes in the range of `0` to `length - 1`.

Comment: Also, you don't really need the `length` variable, since the vector will itself keep track of its "length". And to get the last element of a vector use the [`back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) function.

Comment: Lastly your `pop` function will not work.

Comment: You will have to add some more statements to prevent accessing elements of `vc` when `vc.size()==0` in the `peek` function.

Comment: To understand array indices, try counting your fingers. Start with zero. Assuming you have 10 fingers, you should end up with the last finger being number 9. Where did the finger number 10 go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

```
  void peek(){
     if(vc.size()==0){
         cout<< "The stack is empty"<<endl;
     }
     cout<< vc[length]<<endl; //----> does not work;
  }
```

If vc.size() == 0, you print out a message, and then proceed to index into the empty vector.  You should return inside that `if`, to avoid looking at an invalid index.

Below it you use use a `length` variable, which I presume is the acting the role of the vector's size().  EITHER you need to ensure the vector's size is the same as the stack's logical size (and then you don't need a `length` variable), OR you should be testing if `length` == 0, and not looking at `size()` here.  Otherwise, you could have a positive size of vector, and a length of zero, and what's logically empty may print junk values.

Another serious mistake, your `pop` function:

```
void pop(){
    vc.erase(vc.end()); // <<< MISTAKE
    length--;
}
```

This is erasing the "end" element, which is not a valid position to erase.  Remember, `end` denotes the first place *after* the last valid element in the vector, so your code yields undefined behavior.  You should use the vector function `pop_back` instead, as it does precisely what you want.  It also will reduce the size of the vector, meaning you don't need a `length` variable at all!  Instead you can use the vector's size().

Next, in peek():

```
cout<< vc[length]<<endl;
```

When a vector contains N things, they are indexed from 0..(N-1).  Using the number of elements will go too far into the vector.  Instead, use `length-1` (or `vc.size()-1` after fixing pop()).  However, you can use `vc.back()` to access the last element without any need to compute its offset.

Comment: Thank you so much for this beautiful explanation.